# jQuery: Non linear time interval between slides

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've a little Slider on a Webpage. Now I need for every slide an other time interval.
First here is the code of the slider:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        function getData(){
            $.get( "<some url>", function( data ) {
                $( "section ul" ).html( data );
                $('section ul li:first-child').fadeIn(1000);
            })
        };

        function moveNext(){
            $('section ul li:first-child').fadeOut(1000, function(){
                $('section ul li:first-child').appendTo('section ul');
                $('section ul li:first-child').fadeIn(1000);
            });
        };

    getData();

    setInterval(function(){
        moveNext();
        moveNextFooter();
    }, 10000);
</script>
```

Now there is this part with setInterval wich i would like to change. The duration for the intervall comes from the slide itself... I thought about something like this:

```
<ul>
    <li rel="2000">Slide 1</li>
    <li rel="5000">Slide 2</li>
</ul>
```

_

```
function moveNext(){
    $('section ul li:first-child').fadeOut(1000, function(){
        $('section ul li:first-child').appendTo('section ul');
        $('section ul li:first-child').fadeIn(1000);
        window.setTimeout(moveNext(), parseInt($('section ul li:first-child').attr('rel')));
    });
};
```

So the current broken code is like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        function getData(){
            $.get( "<some url>", function( data ) {
                $( "section ul" ).html( data );
                $('section ul li:first-child').fadeIn(1000);
            })
        };

        function moveNext(){
            $('section ul li:first-child').fadeOut(1000, function(){
            $('section ul li:first-child').appendTo('section ul');
            $('section ul li:first-child').fadeIn(1000);
            window.setTimeout(moveNext(), parseInt($('section ul li:first-child').attr('rel')));
        });
    };

    getData();
</script>

<section>
    <ul>
        <li rel="2000">Slide 1</li>
        <li rel="5000">Slide 2</li>
    </ul>
</section>
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: window.setTimeout(moveNext, ...) http://jsfiddle.net/M6AUx/ can you also describe what is not working?

Comment: well it does make a difference, it's just not the difference you are looking for probably. Please describe what is not working in detail

Comment: It doesn't call the moveNext function. So i think the problem is, that i'm loading the timeintervall after the ajax request.

Comment: Can you post the code that is currently broken. I am confused as to what the final code you have right now which does not work

Comment: The broken part should be this one: `window.setTimeout(moveNext(), parseInt($('section ul li:first-child').attr('rel')));` I think the problem is this section: `parseInt($('section ul li:first-child').attr('rel'))`

Comment: You said the function don't get called where the jquery is inside the function. Please update question with the current broken code. I want to see how everything is called and in what order

Comment: It loads the first slide but then it doesn't change to the next slide (Function moveNext).

Comment: Have you tried moving the function moveNext out of doc ready? It should not be in there. The set interval is called moveNext but that function is inside of the doc ready which is not the same scope

Comment: In your updated code, moveNext is never called so of course it won't run

Comment: I am not sue if it is a typo but your doc ready function is not closed, missing `});`

Comment: I took it out of the doc ready and called it and it worked =) Thanks a lot for your time =)

Comment: you are still missing the closing brackets for doc ready

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Huangism i found the answer.

It was a simple thing i didn't see. I've never called the moveNext Function so it never startet. The correct code is this one:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        function getData(){
            $.get( "<some url>", function( data ) {
                $( "section ul" ).html( data );
                $('section ul li:first-child').fadeIn(1000);
                window.setTimeout(moveNext, parseInt($('section ul li:first-child').attr('rel')));
            })
        };

        function moveNext(){
            $('section ul li:first-child').fadeOut(1000, function(){
                $('section ul li:first-child').appendTo('section ul');
                $('section ul li:first-child').fadeIn(1000);
                window.setTimeout(moveNext, parseInt($('section ul li:first-child').attr('rel')));
            });
    };

    getData();
</script>

<section>
    <ul>
        <li rel="2000">Slide 1</li>
        <li rel="5000">Slide 2</li>
    </ul>
</section>
```

Feel free for using it for yourself =)